# Python Scrapy: follow link and extract data from javascript table

Tags: javascript, python, http, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to get some data from malaysian government bond website (http://bondinfo.bnm.gov.my/portal/server.pt ).

Need to go to:

home page > market activities >historical>historical securities volume

This opens up a new page with a table.
click on MGS from that table and then apply filter for current month and scrap all the data from the filtered out search.

Would be glad if someone could help me understand how this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

The page already has an "export to excel" button on it for free - you don't need to scrape it
[image]

Comment: export to excel works for only 1000 rows at a time and the total amount of rows are very huge. Thereby scraping makes sense.
Also, I would need to do this several times in a month, thereby looking for a scraping solution